# Laravel Store function ignored on production server

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm making a website that 100% works locally but when uploaded to my server everything works except the `Store` function(/route) for `pages`.

Expected behaviour when I click the `Add` button: PageController@store to be executed.

What happens when I click the `Add` button locally: PageController@store gets executed.

What actually happens when I click the `Add` button on my server: It just seems to go to `pages.index` without executing PageController@store.

Let's say I put `return "test";` in the Store function instead of the storing logic and change StoreRequest to Request, it still just goes to `pages.index` without showing the text `test` even though this also does work locally.

Why is this happening? All the code it the same, and all the other routes and functions work perfectly fine. Everything works except saving/storing.

**Routes:**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@welcome')->name('welcome');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('pages', 'PageController');
```

**PageController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StorePage;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePage;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'pages' => Page::all()
        ];
        return view('pages.index')->with($data);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.create');
    }

    public function store(StorePage $request)
    {
        $page = new Page();
        $page->fill($request->all());
        $page->save();
        return Redirect::route('pages.index');
    }

    public function edit(Page $page)
    {
        $data = [
            'page' => $page
        ];
        return view('pages.edit')->with($data);
    }

    public function update(UpdatePage $request, Page $page)
    {
        $page->fill($request->all());
        $page->save();
        return Redirect::route('pages.index');
    }

    public function destroy(Page $page)
    {
        $page->delete();
        return Redirect::route("pages.index");
    }
}
```

**Form:**

```
                        {{Form::open(array('route' => array('pages.store')))}}
                        @method('POST')
                        @csrf
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
                                {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control '.($errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : ''),'required')) }}
                                @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                    <small class="text-danger" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                    </small>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                {{ Form::label('identifier', 'Identifier:') }}
                                {{ Form::text('identifier', null, array('class' => 'form-control '.($errors->has('identifier') ? ' is-invalid' : ''),'required')) }}
                                @if ($errors->has('identifier'))
                                    <small class="text-danger" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('identifier') }}</strong>
                                    </small>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                {{ Form::label('content', 'Content:') }}
                                {{ Form::textarea('content', null, array('class' => 'form-control '.($errors->has('content') ? ' is-invalid' : ''),'required')) }}
                                @if ($errors->has('content'))
                                    <small class="text-danger" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('content') }}</strong>
                                    </small>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                        {{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: replace form code ```Form::open(['route' => 'pages.store'])``` and check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging I saw that the request returned 403 Forbidden. I had a folder called 'pages' which is exactly where the POST request was going: /pages/. Renaming this folder fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some files are cached in the server, so you may not be seeing the effect of your application file changes all the time.

Try clearing and reloading your application and route caches by running these commands on the server cli in order:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache

php artisan config:cache 

composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Tried these comments but nothing changed

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.0